# Form validation and form action not working in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am building my first codeigniter application and trying to figure out how to implement basic authentication feature. Following is my login view:

```
<div><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>
<?php echo form_open('admin/index', ['role' => 'form']); ?>
          <fieldset>
            <legend><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Secure Sign-In</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <?php echo form_input(['name' => 'username', 'id' => 'username', 'class' => 'form-control', 'value' => '']); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <?php echo form_password(['name' => 'password', 'id' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control']) ?>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <?php echo form_checkbox(['name' => 'remember_me', 'value' => 'Remember Me']) ?> Remember Me
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign In
            </button>
            <a class="btn btn-link" href="">Forgot Your Password?</a>
          </fieldset>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Admin controller goes like following:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('auth/login_view');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        $this->load->helper('url','form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'UserName', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');
    }
}
```

When i submit the empty form (no input in user name and password input field), it should ideally perform the validation and display error on login view but it's not. It shows nothing.

Also, When i opened the login view page source in chrome I noticed that the form action value looks a little different. It has following value:

```
<form action="http://[::1]/meshi/index.php/admin/index" role="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

I am not sure what [::1] means in form action. Also, I have not specified base url value in the config file.

Comment: In Codeigniter3 `base_url` setting is mandatory in config.php. After setting it you'll see real url in form action instead of  [::1]

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter3 `base_url` setting is mandatory in config.php. After setting it you'll see real url in form action instead of [::1]

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/meshi/';
```

Second, when you want to see form error you should use `validation_errors()` in view page

```
echo validation_errors();
```

Make sure you load the form helper before use it

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added the base url in the config file and it seems that the form action is now fixed. But i still don't see the validation errors on view. I have updated my view to include validation_errors();

Comment: have loaded form helper?

Comment: Yes. You can see inside the admin controller index function. $this->load->helper('url','form');

Comment: if you don't get any error then its working. perhaps the `<div>` is not visible. view source code

Comment: It's working only after adding an if clause to check if the validation is true or false and loading the views inside the if.                                                         'if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('templates/header');
   $this->load->view('auth/login_view');
   $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
  else
  {
   $this->load->view('successform');
  }'